# Display app theme immediately in Flutter app

Tags: flutter

Given the asynchronous nature of the Flutter shared_prefs plugin, how could one make sure that when an app is launched the correct theme settings are immediately displayed? I.e. no flash of the default theme followed by applying the correct theme once the shared_prefs have finished loading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When your `build` method requires waiting for a `Future`, it's a good time to break out [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

```
void main() {
  runApp(new FutureBuilder(
    future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
    builder: (_, snapshot) {
      return snapshot.hasData ?
             new MyApp(preferences: snapshot.data) :
             new LoadingScreen(); 
    },
  ));
}
```

A few tips for building apps with this pattern:

- `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` is pretty fast. You app may look better with an empty `Container` as a black loading screen instead of a flash of colorful content. However, if you're loading other stuff at the same time, showing your logo makes more sense.
- If you need to await multiple futures, you can use
  [Future.wait](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html) or nest multiple `FutureBuilder`s together.

Answer (score 9):

One way would be to delay the display of your main app with a loading screen.  A pattern I've seen is:

```
main() async {
  runApp(new LoadingScreen());
  runApp(new App(await asyncStuff()));
}
```

You can call runApp as often as you like: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/runApp.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `StatefulWidget` with `setState` to update the root widget after the application configuration is complete.

You can use something like (in short):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _return mainWidget;
}
```

In conjunction with:

```
mainWidget = loadingWidget();
someMethodThatDoesAppConfig().then((Widget configuredWidget) {
    setState(() {
        _mainWidget = configuredWidget;
    });
});
```

Comment: When you're in an async callback, you should check if(mounted) before calling setState to ensure that your widget hasn't been disposed already. Otherwise Flutter will assert. FutureBuilder does this for you automatically. In this specific case it's probably fine because the StatefulWidget is near the root of the app and is unlikely to be unmounted, but it's a good habit when building composable widgets.