# How to load data from cache before app loads in flutter?

Tags: flutter

My flutter app writes data to a file in the device's cache. That data is used in home screen. When I restart the app, I want my app to load that data from that file. How can I do this?

Consider the data to be a list and I've a listview.builder in the home screen. I'm saving that list into a file in cache and I want to retrieve that list and display in home screen everytime when the app launches.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Actually, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379849/display-app-theme-immediately-in-flutter-app?rq=1.