# Flutter - Start app with different routes depending on login state

Tags: navigation, flutter

I'm searching for a way to show a different screens on app startup depending on login state. For example, I have the following routes defined:

- /home
- /login
- /settings

Naturally, I would check if the user has already logged in within the `main()` method and then set the `initialRoute` of my MaterialApp to either /login or /home. After successful login, I can call `Navigator.pushReplacement` to navigate to /home and the login screen is removed from the stack. Unfortunately, I always have to either define a route for `/` or set the `home` property of MaterialApp. So if I set `/` to a blank `Container()`, this Container will be on the navigation stack and the user can go back to this blank screen.

Two options I came up with are:

- Setting the home property of MaterialApp to either HomeScreen or LoginScreen
- Return a LoginScreen within HomeScreen's `build()` method, if the user has not logged in yet

Both options are feasible, but then I have to come up with some reload logic and re-set the state in order to update the home property or HomeScreen.

Any ideas what is the proper way in Flutter to deal with such cases?

Comment: Why don't you call runApp multiple times?
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/runApp.html
It is allowed by flutter team as shown here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44379895/1462442

Answer (score 31):

Maybe, you could do this. Imagine you have a class Auth with an async method `isLogged`.

```dart
class Auth {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<bool> isLogged() async {
    try {
      final FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
      return user != null;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

You could use the `myApp` constructor to pass the `initialRoute`, and decide the initial route depending on the login state. Then, you can pass the instance of `myApp` to `runApp`:

**Warning:** In case of error, add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` just before `void main() async {`. Check this issue [#40253](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40253).

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final Auth _auth = Auth();
  final bool isLogged = await _auth.isLogged();
  final MyApp myApp = MyApp(
    initialRoute: isLogged ? '/home' : '/',
  );
  runApp(myApp);
}
```

After that, you have to modify the `myApp` class to pass the initial route in the constructor:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String initialRoute;

  MyApp({this.initialRoute});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dynamic Route Demo',
      initialRoute: initialRoute,
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => LoginPage(),
        '/home': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/settings': (context) => SettingsPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not working. I get exception on isLogged . failed assertion as bool cant be null

Comment: This is really helpful, specially in case you are working on flutter for web.

Comment: What happens if the refresh token is expired i.e. `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null` as this solution assumes the user will always logout or close the app. You would need to create a stream or `ChangeNotifier` and listen for any `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges` and close/relaunch the app.

Comment: Would it be possible to add this automatic logout in the next request to the backend? Check if the token is valid, and log out the user if not. To avoid being logged out abruptly, doing it in the next action with a proper warning.

Comment: what if i have more than two screens that i want to include with conditions on being the initial screen, i posted a question here if you could help >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955476/flutter-multiple-conditions-on-witch-is-going-to-be-home-screen-using-shared-pre

Comment: For more than one route and more than one condition, maybe you need a helper method to return the correct route for each condition set, @Ajan.

Comment: yeah i fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You should do is move to the route /login (or any other your preferred with login) and set that as initialRoute. And based on that you can modify the onGenerateInitialRoutes property of the app, to make sure that the routes are actually not pushed into Navigator history. That way you override the defaultGenerateInitialRoutes which is pushing those home state on to your Navigator. Check this code snippet from Flutter's site.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/defaultGenerateInitialRoutes.html

Will copy it here as well, just in case link not works in future.

> defaultGenerateInitialRoutes method List
>   defaultGenerateInitialRoutes ( NavigatorState navigator, String
>   initialRouteName ) Turn a route name into a set of Route objects.
>
> This is the default value of onGenerateInitialRoutes, which is used if
>   initialRoute is not null.
>
> If this string contains any / characters, then the string is split on
>   those characters and substrings from the start of the string up to
>   each such character are, in turn, used as routes to push.
>
> For example, if the route /stocks/HOOLI was used as the initialRoute,
>   then the Navigator would push the following routes on startup: /,
>   /stocks, /stocks/HOOLI. This enables deep linking while allowing the
>   application to maintain a predictable route history.

```
static List<Route<dynamic>> defaultGenerateInitialRoutes(NavigatorState navigator, String initialRouteName) {
  final List<Route<dynamic>> result = <Route<dynamic>>[];
  if (initialRouteName.startsWith('/') && initialRouteName.length > 1) {
    initialRouteName = initialRouteName.substring(1); // strip leading '/'
    assert(Navigator.defaultRouteName == '/');
    List<String> debugRouteNames;
    assert(() {
      debugRouteNames = <String>[ Navigator.defaultRouteName ];
      return true;
    }());
    result.add(navigator._routeNamed<dynamic>(Navigator.defaultRouteName, arguments: null, allowNull: true));
    final List<String> routeParts = initialRouteName.split('/');
    if (initialRouteName.isNotEmpty) {
      String routeName = '';
      for (final String part in routeParts) {
        routeName += '/$part';
        assert(() {
          debugRouteNames.add(routeName);
          return true;
        }());
        result.add(navigator._routeNamed<dynamic>(routeName, arguments: null, allowNull: true));
      }
    }
    if (result.last == null) {
      assert(() {
        FlutterError.reportError(
          FlutterErrorDetails(
            exception:
              'Could not navigate to initial route.\n'
              'The requested route name was: "/$initialRouteName"\n'
              'There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be '
              'ignored and "${Navigator.defaultRouteName}" will be used instead.'
          ),
        );
        return true;
      }());
      result.clear();
    }
  } else if (initialRouteName != Navigator.defaultRouteName) {
    // If initialRouteName wasn't '/', then we try to get it with allowNull:true, so that if that fails,
    // we fall back to '/' (without allowNull:true, see below).
    result.add(navigator._routeNamed<dynamic>(initialRouteName, arguments: null, allowNull: true));
  }
  // Null route might be a result of gap in initialRouteName
  //
  // For example, routes = ['A', 'A/B/C'], and initialRouteName = 'A/B/C'
  // This should result in result = ['A', null,'A/B/C'] where 'A/B' produces
  // the null. In this case, we want to filter out the null and return
  // result = ['A', 'A/B/C'].
  result.removeWhere((Route<dynamic> route) => route == null);
  if (result.isEmpty)
    result.add(navigator._routeNamed<dynamic>(Navigator.defaultRouteName, arguments: null));
  return result;
}
```