# changing initial route according to get request

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that starts in the login page as initial route. I want to check if the users' token is still valid, and if it is, I want to go directly to another route instead of the login page.

I have all the server logic and am making a get request that returns a boolean to say if the user session(token) is valid.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var initRoute;
    if (_isTokenValid() as bool){
      initRoute = '/login';
    }else{
      initRoute = '/main';
    }
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
            currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Mappin',
        theme: Themes.lightAppTheme,
        darkTheme: Themes.darkAppTheme,
        initialRoute: initRoute,
        routes: {
          '/main': (context) => NavBar(),
          '/profile': (context) => ProfilePage(),
          '/settings': (context) => SettingsPage(),
          '/messageDetail': (context) => MessageDetail(),
          '/login': (context) => LoginPage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
Future<bool> _isTokenValid() async {
    // in this function we can pass the controlers directly bcs they are declared in the class. In login they are declared inside each widget (login/signup)
    final isValid = await APIService().isAccessValid();
    if (!isValid){
      return await APIService().isRefreshValid();
    }
    return isValid;
  }

}
```

The Problem with this code is that casting `Future<bool>` to `bool` is invalid. In other pages I would set the state of a variable, but since app is a stateless widget, this is not possible.

**What is a good way of receiving a boolean from the GET request (async function) and changing the initial route according to its value?**

Comment: I ended up finding a similar question: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194574/flutter-start-app-with-different-routes-depending-on-login-state". This solved my problem. Mods can close for duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

What is being received from the APIService? That might be why you are getting that error.

Try adding a toggle breakpoint on

```
Future<bool> _isTokenValid() async {
```

To see where the problems from.

Comment: APIService is reading the error from data and also returning a future bool, this function isTokenValid is used to verify first the access and then the refresh token and simplify the process. The error is related with not being possible to transform the future<bool> into bool. Because the solution I tried is no good. What I'm asking is for another way of doing this that would work here.

Answer (score 0):

`FutureBuilder` can help you to get a callback

```
FutureBuilder(
        // get the Provider, and call the _isTokenValid method
        future: _isTokenValid(),
        // wait for the future to resolve and render the appropriate
        // widget for HomePage or LoginPage
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return snapshot.hasData ? NavBar() : LoginPage();
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
```

Comment: It makes sense but it says for both the future and the builder the error " the default value of an optional parameter must be constant". This is not the response of the get directly but it should still be a future bool so it should work, right?

Comment: check the bool value in data, until then you can show splash screen or progress indicator